# Search for a design of single-writer-multi-reader multithreading communication

Tags: multithreading, condition-variable

The application context is as follows:

1. It is a single-process-multi-threads program
2. It is designed for automated-futures-trading. In futures trading market, there are hundreds of active future contracts. Market data of each contract is called tick-data which is pushed from Future-Exchange every 500 ms. Each automated-futures-trading strategy runs as a thread. Each strategy needs  the real time market data of different contracts. For example: strategy A needs market data of contract A1, contract A2 and contract A3. Strategy B needs market data of contract A1, contract B1 and contract B2.
3. One thread in this program runs as a market data receiver which receives the market data of all the contracts and saves them in a data buffer which could be saved to disk database after trading. So this thread could be reviewed as a data producer and Strategy threads could be reviewed as data consumers. So this scenario is a single-producer-multi-consumers problem. The design must make sure all the strategy threads could get the tick-data they need efficiently.
4. One possible design is that: all consumers wait for a condition variable and try to get a shared lock. When a new tick comes, the single producer tries to get an exclusive lock and save this tick data into the data buffer. Then it notify all the consumers with condition variable. When a consumer is notified, it will retrieve the data buffer to see whether the contract data it needs are updated (by comparing the timestamp ). If no, it will wait for the condition variable again. But this design of low efficiency, each new coming tick data will cause all the consumers to wake up and retrieve the data buffer (the course of retrieval may be time-consuming) whether the consumer needs the data or not.
5. An improved design is that: define a global variable to store the new coming tick data. When a new tick data comes, the producer will update the global variable as well as store the tick data into the data buffer, then notify all the consumers. The consumers wake up and just check the global variable to see if the tick data is of their need(without retrieve the whole data buffer). But the problem is that there exists some race condition. May be before the consumer gets the shared lock, another new tick data comes and the producer gets the lock ahead and updates the global variable. So one tick data would be missed by the consumers.
   Is there a better design? (e.g. using unix domain socket to broadcast? I don’t know whether unix domain socket could be applied between multi-threads. If so, what about the efficiency comparing shared memory?)

Comment: Can you not keep a list[contract] of lists[strategy] that is built and maintained my one thread that waits on an input queue for tick data etc. messages and, upon receipt, loads the new data into a message that is then queued with every strategy that is listed/registered for data for that contract?  The strategy class, together with its message, could then be processed by its own thread.  If each strategy has an input queue for messages, it may well be possible to use a threadpool for processing the strategies.

Comment: If you can tell us what language you are using there are plenty of already existing efficient producer-consumer mechanisms that we can suggest. It's probably better to just use some of them in code and do some benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks , Tudor, Thanks for your attention. The design is programmed using C++ on the platform of linux.

Comment: In both of your designs ALL strategy threads are woken up upon new data. While you mention "single-producer-multi-consumer" (which means you are on the correct track)... in what you describe you are just accessing shared data. Have a look at "producer consumer problem" and maybe "publish subscribe pattern" on wikipedia.